# regex sub not working when used with filter

Tags: python, regex, filter

I have a list of strings which contain special characters

`state_list = [('Andhra Pradesh',), ('Karnataka',)]`

It works fine like this

```
for state in state_list:
    print(re.sub(r'\W+'," ",str(state)))
```

output

> Andhra Pradesh
>
> Karnataka

When i use filter to do this

```
list(filter(lambda state: re.sub(r"\W+", " ", str(state)),state_list))
```

It doesn't work!
I get back the list unaltered.

`[('Andhra Pradesh',), ('Karnataka',)]`

I am expecting a list like this
`['Andhra Pradesh','Karnataka']`

I want the special characters like `(`,`)` and `,` to be removed from a list of strings

Comment: Maybe you wanted `map`? `list(map(lambda state: re.sub(r"\W+", " ", state[0]),state_list))`?

Comment: `map` not helping, data type of each item in the list is `class 'sqlalchemy.util._collections.result'` so need to convert it into `str` first to use `re`

Comment: But you showed a list of tuples. Try `tuple(state)[0]`, `list(map(lambda state: re.sub(r"\W+", " ", str(tuple(state)[0])),state_list))`

Comment: `unique_state_list = partnerTableSession.query(partnerTable.c.state).distinct().all()` gives me a list like `[('Andhra Pradesh',), ('Karnataka',)]` when `unique_state_list` is printed on screen. `data type` of each element in the list is `class 'sqlalchemy.util._collections.result'`

Comment: The point is to get the item separately. Then case it to `str`

Comment: I want it in a list as mentioned above. I'm using `str()` to convert  `class 'sqlalchemy.util._collections.result'` inside `re.sub(r'\W+'," ",str(state))`

Comment: I think you are considering your list as follows state_list1 = ['(Andhra Pradesh,)', '(Karnataka,)'] not as tuple elements

Answer (score 0):

re.sub() doesn't perform overlapping replacement. You need your own loop and that's why it worked in the first case with for loop.

List comprehension will be ideal way to achieve this:

```
[state[0] for state in state_list]
```

Output:

```
['Andhra Pradesh', 'Karnataka']
```